# Keep params after render Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have a Project that belongs to User. In my user view I have a link to add a new project, with the parameter for the user I want to add the project to.

```
<%= link_to 'Add new project', :controller => "project", :action => "new", :id => @user %>

Url: /projects/new?id=62
```

Adding a project to a user works. The problem is when the validation fails while adding a new project and I do a render.

```
def create

    @project = Project.new(params[:project])

    if @project.save
        redirect_to :action => "show", :id => @project.id
    else
        render :action => "new"
    end

end
```

view:

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id , :value => params[:id] %>

    <%= f.submit "Create project" %>
<% end %>
```

routes

```
resources :users do
 resources :projects
end
```

How can I keep the parameter for the user after the render? Or is there some better way to do this? Been looking at a lot of similar questions but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
render :action => "new", :id => @project.id
```

if its not works for you, then try alternate way to pass the parameter to your render action.

This can also help you->
[Rails 3 Render => New with Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672585/rails-3-render-new-with-parameter)

Comment: which version of rails you are using?

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use `params[:id]` to assign value to this form field. Instead, add this to your `#new` action in controller:

```
def new
  @project = Project.new(user_id: params[:id])
end
```

and then just write this in your form:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>
```

Because `@project` was defined in your `#new` and `#create` actions and because it already contains a Project instance with a `user_id` assigned to it, the value would automatically be added to this field.

Comment: this is the rails way guys follow this, assigned the value manually using params[:id] will give u more trouble since the `render :new` for failed forms not returning the params automatically thus why the question is asked at first