# Losing params in url of a simple form when rendering new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, simple-form

I created a simple_form in my Ruby on Rails app. It's working fine except when there is an error in the form, and the form is reloaded, at this moment I lose the params in the url.

(I Already read [Keep params after render Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975486/keep-params-after-render-ruby-on-rails)  and [Rails 3 Render => New with Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672585/rails-3-render-new-with-parameter))

Here is the controller code:

```
def new
  @parts = Part.where(id: params[:part_id])
  @part = params[:part_id]
  @traveller = Traveller.new
end

def create
  if @traveller.save
    redirect_to edit_part_path(:id => @traveller.part_id)
    flash[:notice] = t('alert.create')
  else
    @part = [:traveller][:part_id]
    @parts = Part.where(id: params[:part_id])
    render :action => "new", :part_id => @part
  end
end
```

And here is the view code

```
<%= simple_form_for @traveller, html: { class: "sigPad"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :surname %>
  <%= f.input :part_id , label: 'part',readonly: true, input_html: {id: 'part_id', value: params[:part_id] }%>
<% end %>
```

I check if the part_id is submited and it is.

My question is how can I keep the part_id in params when the page is reloaded. Note

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,

in action new:

```
@traveller.part_id = params[:part_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same problem with a verification in controller action new:

Example :

```
if params[:part_id]
  @traveller.part_id = params[:part_id]
elsif params[:traveller][:part_id]
  @traveller.part_id = params[:traveller][:part_id]
end
```

Because the user can fail one or many times in register