# How to get hidden_field to work when validation fails in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

I have a hidden field in a form_for, where I have it set up like this:

```
  = f.hidden_field :building_id, :value => @building
```

Where @building is set in the controller in the new action:

```
@building = params[:building][:building_id]
```

When validation fails, the create action gets to this line:

```
format.html { render action: "new" }
```

and the page is rendered, the hidden_field is not getting it's value.

According to one of the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549055/rails-pass-parameters-with-render-action), it looks like maybe I should have this line in my form_for:

```
  = f.hidden_field :building_id, params[:building][building_id]
```

but I get an error when I do this.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `params[:building][:building_id]` is no longer set when you load the page after a validation error occurs, as it's now stored in `params[:building_id]`. Something like `@building = params[:building_id] || params[:building][:building_id]` should work fine.

Comment: Right idea!  I had to set the parameters in the create action of the controller, such as @building = [:<singular-version-of-controller-name>][:building_id].

Comment: Ah sorry yes, wasn't thinking about the fact that it was setup to call from a form already, not just a hidden_field_tag.