# Render error on new page with customize url like http://localhost:3000/education_informations/new?user_id=10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to pass query parameter with new action  http://localhost:3000/education_informations/new?user_id=10 and also set form validation on it. when form submit failed so its display error but url is changes like http://localhost:3000/education_informations so I want to same customize url and pass query parameter with user_id. Please help me

controller code give below

```
def create
    @edu_info = EducationInformations.new(educational_params)

        if @edu_info.save
            #flash[:notice] = 'Vote saved.'
            redirect_to @edu_info
        else
            render 'new'
        end     

end
```

Comment: Why do you need this `user_id` in url. Generally this should not be done. If you explain your case or issue/difficulty why you are doing this or what you need to do we can help you more.

Comment: I have many user in dashboard when i click on username so i am able to create new record for that user thats why i am passing using id with specific user. Is it sufficient or not? @Deep

Comment: So instead of passing it that way why don't you make a route like:  http://localhost:3000/users/10/education_informations/new which is the standard way to do it

Comment: Can you give me example? Thanks

Comment: Can you post your form code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the ***parameters*** to the `form_for` like below to keep `user_id` in the ***URL*** even after the ***form submission failed***.

```
<%= form_for @edu_info, :url => { :action => :create, :user_id => @user.id } %>
```

**or**

```
<%= form_for @edu_info, :url => { :action => :create, :user_id => current_user.id } %>
```

If `@user` is not initialised.

[***Source***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549055/rails-pass-parameters-with-render-action)

Answer (score 1):

I am supposing that the education information will always be realted to the user. So to create the route you should do as:

In routes file:

```
resources :users do
  resources :education_informations
end
```

So what this will do is create the route as I specified in the comments. Like this will be routes:

```
user_education_informations     GET    /users/:user_id/education_informations(.:format)          education_informations#index
                                POST   /users/:user_id/education_informations(.:format)          education_informations#create
 new_user_education_information GET    /users/:user_id/education_informations/new(.:format)      education_informations#new
edit_user_education_information GET    /users/:user_id/education_informations/:id/edit(.:format) education_informations#edit
     user_education_information GET    /users/:user_id/education_informations/:id(.:format)      education_informations#show
                                PATCH  /users/:user_id/education_informations/:id(.:format)      education_informations#update
                                PUT    /users/:user_id/education_informations/:id(.:format)      education_informations#update
                                DELETE /users/:user_id/education_informations/:id(.:format)      education_informations#destroy
                          users GET    /users(.:format)                                          users#index
                                POST   /users(.:format)                                          users#create
                       new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                                      users#new
                      edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                                 users#edit
                           user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                      users#show
                                PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                                      users#update
                                PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                                      users#update
                                DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                                      users#destroy
```

So for the new eudcation information form you need to give this path `new_user_education_information_path(user)` where `user` will be the clicked user.

You can get more information here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not using This way nested resource but Learn from this answer how to take nested resources...@Deep Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use `redirect_to` with url parameters.

In your `#create` action you will have your current `user_id` params:

```
user_id = params[:user_id]
```

If you want to `redirect_to` `@edu_info` and keep the params, you can set them via the options hash on the `redirect_to` method:

```
redirect_to @edu_info(user_id: user_id)
```

Does that make sense to you?

Comment: No reason to downvote my answer…
The accepted answer shows me that I couldn't understand your question properly. My bad.

Comment: Sorry for that Its my mistake click on downarrow. Thanks to you because you gave me response first. @Holger Frohloff